# Querying all objects that don't exist in another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models, Picture and SubmittedPicture as follows:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
pic = ImageField(upload_to='userpics/%Y/%m/%d/%H')

class SubmittedPicture(models.Model):
picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, unique=True)
description = models.TextField()
submitted_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, I need to query for all Pictures which do not have a corresponding SubmittedPicture.
I tried several options, but none of them was functional.

I read through the Django-doc, but couldn't find something useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Picture.objects.filter(submittedpicture__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Didn't know that `submittedpicture` was kind of a "reverse" field.

Comment: If you don't set up a `related_name` on the field, it defaults to lowercase version of class name. Otherwise, it would be your `related_name`.